# jQuery data-attribute is cutting of leading zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to grab a data-* with jQuery.  My problem is that jQuery reads my string of numbers as a number and as such drops the leading zero.

**HTML**

```
<tr data-string-number="0123456789">... (website layout, jk) ...</tr>
```

**jQuery 1.7.2**

```
var string_number = $('#selector').data('string-number');
// string_number == 123456789
// string_number != '0123456789'
```

Seems simple enough however this always drops the leading zero.

`data-string-number` is always going to be a number and may or may not have a leading zero.  Currently it has a standard length but I can't say at this point if that will stay true.

Current only thought is to prefix it with a non-numeric and remove it straight away.  This feels hacky and makes me sad.

Any thought appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all.  All right but nnnnnn has the best description. (easy points ;-) )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#selector').attr('data-string-number')
```

The `.data()` method does data conversion *by design*. The `.attr()` method simply returns the attribute as is (as a string). Note that when using `.attr()` you need to supply the full name of the attribute including the `"data-"` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but I have 2 alternative to using the .attr() for accessing the data as a string.

```
<!-- Force a String by breaking the parser Remove Quotes later
or Use Object Below -->
<li data-tmp='"0123456789"'>Data as a String: </li>
<li data-tmp='{"num":123456789,"str":"0123456789"}'>Data as a Object: </li>
```

Now you can access them with the jQuery .data() method.

See this fiddle to illustrate http://jsfiddle.net/KUrJ2/.

Comment: +1 for providing alternatives. When storing as an object the properties can also be accessed using $("li").data("tmp").num & $("li").data("tmp").str

Answer (score 1):

Get the attribute with the standard `attr()` accessor.

jQuery tries to *guess* the type and convert it when using `data()` on `data-*` attributes. As we know leading `0`'s are insignificant in a `Number` but not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery attr()

http://jsfiddle.net/duerq/